# Drag fragment up and down

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have the main activity which is composed by two fragments one called Canvas and the other is the Palette. In the main activity, the palette only appears on 25% of the screen and I want to make it possible so that the user can drag it up and down to choose colors from it. I have no idea how to do it.

### main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/canvasFragment"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/paletteFragment"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### mainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.paint;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**Canvas**/
        // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment canvasFragment = new CanvasFragment();
        //canvasFragment.getView().setBackgroundColor(this.cor);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.canvasFragment, canvasFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

        /**Palette**/
        // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment paletteFragment = new PaletteFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction2.replace(R.id.paletteFragment, paletteFragment);
        transaction2.addToBackStack(null);
        // Commit the transaction
        transaction2.commit();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


}
```

### PaletteFragment.java:

```
package com.example.paint;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior;
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment;

public class PaletteFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette, container, false);
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BottomSheetDialogFragment to achieve required results. This is a dialog fragment in Android Material Library.

You have to have to extend your Palette fragment with BottomSheetDialogFragment and simply use following lines to show it in Activity:

```
PaletteFragment paletteFragment = new PaletteFragment();
paletteFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAGTEXT");
```

In your PaletteFragment, add listener for palette to slide using BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(). On this callback you can update palette height on slide.

Comment: I replace the part where I add the paletteFragment in the main for `PaletteFragment paletteFragment = new PaletteFragment();
paletteFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAGTEXT");` 
and I extended the palette with the bottomSheetDialogFragment. Now for the listener I do it like `onDrag(){... BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback `  and do I do this part in the main or in the fragment class?

Comment: Add BottomSheetCallback in Fragment class

Comment: Do i make a new method or do it in the onCreate() ?

Comment: I'm seriously not understanding this part

Comment: Should I replace in my mainActivity.java the part where I have `PaletteFragment paletteFragment = new PaletteFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction2.replace(R.id.paletteFragment, paletteFragment);
        transaction2.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction2.commit();`
for 
`PaletteFragment paletteFragment = new PaletteFragment();
paletteFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAGTEXT");`

Comment: Add Like this in onViewCreated
val bottomSheetDialog = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener { dialog ->
    val d = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
    val bottomSheet = d.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout?
    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet!!)
    mBottomSheetBehavior?.setBottomSheetCallback(object: BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(){
        override fun onStateChanged(p0: View, p1: Int) {
        }
        override fun onSlide(p0: View, p1: Float) {
        }
    })
}

Comment: U're writing in Kotlin but I'm using Java. Can you write it in Java I don't know how to convert it.

Comment: Dialog bsd = this.getDialog();
bsd.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
Override 
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
 BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
FrameLayout bottomSheet = d.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
Override
 public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
}
Override
public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
}
});
}
});